# Apart may use Padé method: what's that?

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, polynomials, implementation-details

How does `Apart` work? The page `tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation#7441` says, "`Apart` uses either a version of the Padé technique or the method of undetermined coefficients.

I know what the latter is (clear of fractions, collect by powers of the variable, equate coefficients of corresponding powers, solve the resulting linear system). What's the former?

(I know what Padé approximation is.)

Comment: Shouldn't this be asked on Math.SE?

Comment: I was hoping at least for some starting direction from somebody knowledgeable about the *Mathematica* internals, so I know what to ask elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

I believe it's the theorem 1.4.4 [**here**](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=Vkk4JNLKbLoC&pg=PA31&lpg=PA31&dq=%22Pad%C3%A9%22+%22partial+fractions%22&source=bl&ots=kSWhHnWmR2&sig=c_r8gz6Y_KixPP-RMGl23_Q7JuQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAjgKahUKEwjX1OPA7O_HAhXITZAKHXN4CdA#v=onepage&q=%22Pad%C3%A9%22%20%22partial%20fractions%22&f=false) that shows the relationship between the Padé Table and the partial fractions expansion.

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]